# Getting command running in a tmux pane

Tags: tmux

Is there a way to show the command which is currently running at a tmux pane?

I tried 'history', but it does not seem to show the commands which I had executed at tmux.

I also tried 'ps -ef', but it does not show the full command in the case like "./a.sh ; ./b.sh"

Comment: `./a.sh; ./b.sh` isn't a command; it's a command *line* that only has meaning to the shell that reads it. `tmux` only knows which command is *currently* running in a pane, either `a.sh` or `b.sh`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found several answers online that include `ps ... | tail -1`. Unfortunately, these don't always work because sometimes the order of the commands is swapped, e.g. for two separate panes I get:

```bash
$ ps -t /dev/pts/12 -o args=
-bash
mpv some_movie.mp4
$ ps -t /dev/pts/10 -o args=
micro some_file.txt
-bash
```

I *really* wanted a single line of output so that I could show it in the status bar, but what I ultimately ended up going with is `ps --forest` via run-shell. It seems to always reliably show the correct order and with more information should there be nested commands running (e.g. via a bash script). Its output looks like:

```bash
$ ps --forest -o args -g $$
COMMAND
-bash
 \_ ps --forest -o args -g 1695
```

**Solution**

So in my .tmux.conf, I've got:

```
bind '`' run-shell 'ps --forest -o pid,args -g #{pane_pid}'
```

It will replace the contents of your pane with the output from the `ps --forest` command. Once you type `esc` or `^C`, the `ps` output disappears, and your pane goes back to whatever it was doing :) Ends up looking like:

[image: running nested scripts]
*running `script.sh`, which calls `other-script.sh`, which sleeps for 30s*

[image: viewing process tree]
*viewing pane process tree via keybinding*

Answer (score 1):

(Old question but for future reference)

Try: `tmux list-panes -t <your_pane_name> -F '#{pane_current_command}'`

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#FORMATS

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `pane-border-status` to `bottom` or `top` in your configuration file, with the tmux command prompt or just running `tmux set pane-border-status bottom`. Borders should appear around the panes and info about the current process appears much like in a regular terminal window's title bar.

I suspect the command wasn't written to the `history` file as the shell with the stuck/long-running job wasn't done yet.

You might try `pstree -U` to see process in their parent/child tree.